# Add prefixes and namespaces to XML serialisation WITHOUT amending C# XSD class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, prefix

We use an XSD file, [published by Agresso](http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14/ABWSchemaLib.xsd) 
to generate our XML files.

I have generated and XSD class, using xsd.exe, and can successfully generate XML files as per customers requests.

The namespaces area looks like

```
<ABWInvoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">
```

And I achieve it by the following code:

```
public static string XmlNamespace<T>(T entity) where T: class
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; //removing the encoding, e.g. instead of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> should be <?xml version="1.0"?>

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("agrlib", "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14");
            ns.Add("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xser.Serialize(writer, entity, ns);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

We have now a customer, requiring and additional prefix to be added: "xsi:schemaLocation",so it will be

```
<ABWInvoice xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">
```

I have found many examples on the web, but they all add **xmlns**:schemaLocation and not **xsi**:schemaLocation. Also I cannot modify xsd class, as it will affect other customers.

As I am new to C# can one advise how to address such a request, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do that *in code* would be to add something like:

```
public class YourRootType
{
    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Bar {
        get => "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14"; 
        set { }
    }
}
```

but this impacts all instances. An alternative might be to add the value via something like XSLT, but that is ugly. If you're happy to leave it in code, you could use **conditional serialization**, i.e. only output it when set; for example:

```
[XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public string Bar { get; set; }
// this pattern is recognized by the serializer itself
public bool ShouldSerializeBar() => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Bar);
```

and set `Bar` to `"http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14"` at runtime for those clients.

Another option would be to use `[XmlAnyAttribute]`:

```
[XmlAnyAttribute]
XmlAttribute[] AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
```

and attach *arbitrary additional attributes* at runtime. That is a bit more complex, though, because it is a bit awkward to get hold of an `XmlAttribute` instance through C# - you need to create a DOM etc.

---

I forgot to say; in terms of making it `xsi:schemaLocation` : that's where `XmlSerializerNamespaces` comes in:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
ns.Add("agrlib", "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14");
// etc
```

and pass `ns` in as the last argument on `XmlSerializer.Serialize`.

Comment: Too complex for a C# newbie, but giving it a go now!

An only thing I didn't understand is how Bar in your example will be associated with schemaLocation. Can you explain it, please?
Much appreciated.

Comment: @KDWolf what your 3rd-party is asking you to do *is not* to add a namespace or prefix or anything like that; they're asking you to add an *attribute*, with local name `"schemaLocation"`, in the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, with the value `"http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14"` - and preferably to *also* have a namespace alias `"xsi"` which corresponds to the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace, with the effect that your attribute can also be referenced via `"xsi:schemaLocation"`. The `[XmlAttribute]` on `Bar` (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) defines the name and namespace; the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` defines the set of namespace aliases, and the value comes from the code shown. So that's how it all ties together. Does that answer the question? or is it still unclear?

Comment: yes, it does indeed! Ta. Apologies I have not enough reputation to mark your answer as useful (requires minimum 15).

Comment: Thank you, @Marc. It really did the trick. May I ask you two more questions, please: 1) when I have added `ns.Add("", "");` as in your example, all the elements had a q1 prefix, e.g. `<q1:ABWInvoice xmlns:agrlib="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14" xmlns:q1="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">
  <q1:Invoice>` Have I had to add something else?   (1/2)

Comment: My second question, is it possible to change the order, so xsi:schemaLocation will be first: `<ABWInvoice xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns="http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">`

Comment: @KDWolf not AFAIK - at least, not without using `XmlWriter` directly. However, the order of attributes in xml is **defined** as being insignificant (see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags, "Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant."). If anyone complains about the order of attributes: they're processing xml incorrectly.